# Solution to handling data that frequently changes

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to figure out a solution to best optimize for data that is going to frequently change. The server is running IIS/SQL Server and it is an ASP.NET Web API application. My table structure is something like the following:

User Table: 
UserID PK

Status Table:
StatusID PK,
Title varchar

UserStatus Table:
UserID PK (CLUSTERED),
StatusID FK (NON-CLUSTERED),
Date DateTimeOffset (POSSIBLY INDEXED) - This would be used as an expiration. Old records become irrelevant.

There will be roughly 5000+ records in the users table. The status table will have roughly 500 records. The UserStatus table would have frequent changes (change every 5-30 seconds) to the StatusID and Date Fields by anywhere from 0 - 1000 users at any given time. This UserStatus table will also have frequent SELECT queries performed against it as well filtering out records with old/irrelevant dates.

- I have considered populating the UserStatus table with a record for
  each user and only performing updates. This would mean there would
  always be the expected record present and it would limit the checks
  for existence. My concern is performance and all of the fragmenting
  of the indexes. I would then query against the table for records with
  dates that fall within several minutes of the current time.
- I have considered only inserting relevant records to the
  UserStatus table, updating when they exist for a user, and running
  a task that cleans old/irrelevant data out. This method would keep
  the number of records down but I would have to check for the
  existence of records before performing a task and indexes may inhibit
  performance.
- Finally I have considered a MemoryCache or something of the like. I
  do not know much about caching in a Web API, but from what I have
  read about it, I quickly decided against this because of potential
  concurrency issues when iterating over the cache.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a scenario like this? Is there another methodology I am not considering?

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of records you are talking about I would use the tsql Merge that will update existing records and add new ones with one efficient statement.

Given the design you mentioned, you should be able to run a periodic maint script that will fix any fragmentation issues.

The solution can be scaled.  If the records got the the point where some slowdown was occurring I would consider SSD where fragmentation is not an issue.

If the disadvantages of SSD make that undesirable you can look into in-memory OLTP.

Comment: he mentions "Old records become irrelevant." with such small dataset he could use table variables @some_fancy_table as long as it retains the connection. More details are needed i guess...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. If by using table variables, you mean doing bulk insert/updates this would not work under this scenario. Each user will be sending their status to the server independently of one another potentially as often as every 5-30 seconds. Only the smaller subset of users will be broadcasting their status to the server but everyone can query the status of "active" users. This is where the date/irrelevant records come into play. Only users who had a status change within the last 5 minutes, for example, should return in a select statement.